# Как изменить template в Marionette LayoutView

Tags: javascript, marionette.js

У меня есть темплейт вида:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="main">
    <div class="table_select">
         <div class="tselect" name="table-region" id="table-region"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="state"></div> // здесь пока пусто
    <div class="i_fform"></div> // здесь пока пусто
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="first">
    <div class="get_state">...</div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="second">
    <div class="file_form">...</div>
</script>
```

И есть LayoutView (Marionette 2.4.1) вида

```
var MainView = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: $(html).filter('#main')[0].outerHTML,
    regions: {
        tableRegion: '#table-region',
        get_state: '.state',
        file_form: '.i_fform',
    },
    onRender: function(){
        // Здесь выполняется некоторый код,
        // по его результатам мне нужно подгрузить
        // либо шаблон с id="first", либо шаблон с id="second",
        // оставив при этом содержимое id="main",
        // и я не знаю, что нужно добавить в this.template,
        // или как изменить сам $(html)
    },
```

В `MainView.onRender` выполняется код, по итогам которого нужно добавить элементы либо из шаблона с `id="first"`, либо из `id="second"`, оставив при этом содержимое `id="main"`. Нужно как-то изменить `this.template` или добавить какие-то ссылки в соответствующие дивы `id="main"`?

Comment: Раньше шаблон был в одном скрипте (никаких filter) и всё работало, но меня попросили отрефакторить в таком виде... Из-за разницы в рабочих графиках я не могу сейчас спросить совета у проверяющего.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вам надо создать по отдельной вьюхе для 'first' и 'second', потом обратиться к нужному региону и отрисовать в нем нужную вьюху в духе this.regions.get_state.show(firstView); Собственно пара первых абзацев в доке по регионам: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.region.html

Answer (score 0):

Как написал в комментарии @Утка , в js-файле нужно создать несколько View-объектов.

```
var MainView = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: $(html).filter('#main')[0].outerHTML,
    regions: {
        tableRegion: '#table-region',
        get_state: '.state',
        file_form: '.i_fform',
    },
    onRender: function(){
        this.get_state.show(SecondView, {/*options*/});
    }
});

var SecondView = new Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: $(html).filter('#second')[0].outerHTML,
    // здесь можно описать свои регионы, триггеры, функции
});
```